# Setting Lines From A File to a Variable in Batch Script

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to make a batch file that will go through a text file of computer names and get the username that is logged in on each.  I am not sure how to set the variables I need within the loops.  I have tried several of the solutiions that I have found on here but none of them seem to work.  output.txt contains:

```
PCHTW-HTT10425 

PCHTW-HTT10437
```

These are the computer names that I am trying to pass.  When I `echo %%A` it gives the names, but setting name to %%A does nothing.  Reading up on it I thought adding in the `SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion` would do the trick but it appears to have done nothing. I have also tried `echo name:!name!` but it also doesn't work.

```
 for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (%FILEPATH%output.txt) do (
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        echo %%A
        SET /p name=%%A
        echo name:%name%
        FOR /F "tokens=2 delims=\" %%F IN ('wmic /NODE:"%name%" computersystem get UserName') DO (
            SET username=%%F
        )
        echo %username%
        pause
        ENDLOCAL
    )
```

Comment: you need [delayed expansion](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2152082). Delete `SET /p name=%%A`. Don't set `%username%`, it's a systemvariable - choose another name, maybe `%usrname%`. (you don't need the variable `%name%`- just use `%%A` instead).

Comment: @Stephan Would I then be able to pass !usrname! on to another command. For example if I wanted to schedule a task on a computer could I do `schtasks /Create /ru !usrname!`?

Comment: Yes, why not? Inside the `for` loop you can even use `schtasks /Create /ru  %%F` - wait - there is that ugly `CR`... Wait, I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (%FILEPATH%output.txt) do (
  echo %%A
  FOR /F "tokens=2 delims=\" %%F IN ('wmic /NODE:"%%A" computersystem get UserName') DO (
    for /f "delims=" %%B in ("%%F") do ( 
      echo %%B
      schtasks /create /ru %%B ...
    )
  )
  pause
)
```

NOTE: `wmic` has ugly line endings (an additional Carriage Return), so there is some more code to get rid of that. I used [one of several possibilities](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34695095/2152082) from dbenham.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is **HOW TO GET LOGGEDON USER FOR A LIST OF COMPUTERS**

How does my correct answer not answer the question. MINE IS ONE LINE.

```
wmic /output:"c:\Outputfile.html" /node:@"COMPUTERLIST.TXT" computersystem get username /format:htable
```

Putting an `@` sign in front of node means node contains a text file of computernames or IP addresses (you can mix and match).

See `wmic /?`, `wmic /node /?`, `wmic /output /?`, `wmic /append /?`, `wmic computersystem /?`, `wmic computersystem get /?`, `wmic computersystem call /?`, `wmic computersystem set /?`, `wmic /format /?`.

To get a list of currently turned on computers

```
for /f "skip=3" %A in ('net view ^| findstr /v /C:"The command completed successfully"') do Echo %A
```

And without leading `\\` as required by wmic

```
for /f "skip=3 delims=\" %%A in ('net view ^| findstr /v /C:"The command completed successfully"') do Echo %%A
```