# Why can the wmic data from a text file not be processed because of some weird character coding problem?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I've been working on a little script that determines which disk is usable in our specific system. There has to be basically less than 1 TB of space on the disk in order to be considered as usable.

This is the complete code:

```
@echo off

chcp 65001>nul
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

wmic logicaldisk get caption,freespace>c:\cmd\1\getDiskInfo.txt

for /f "tokens=1,2 eol=C" %%I in (C:\cmd\1\getDiskInfo.txt) do (
    set diskCaption=%%I
    set diskFreeSpace=%%J
    set captionFreeSpace=!diskCaption! !diskFreeSpace!

    for /f "tokens=1,2 delims= " %%X in ("!captionFreeSpace!") do (
        if [%%Y] neq [] set usedDisks=%%X %%Y

        for /f "tokens=1,2 delims= " %%A in ("!usedDisks!") do (
            set freeSpaceFirstChar=%%B
            set /a freeSpaceFirstChar=!freeSpaceFirstChar:~0,1!

            if !freeSpaceFirstChar! gtr 1 set usableDisk=%%A
        )
    )
)

echo %usableDisk%

pause
```

But the output I get for `%usableDisk%` is always `ECHO is off.` which means that `%usableDisk%` does not even exist. I've done a little investigation and from my understanding it's because of a character coding related problem. I've copied the content of `getDiskInfo.txt` to another .txt file, and the batch file managed to give me the right output with that text file created by me.
The contents of `getDiskInfo.txt` and the other text file was both:

```
Caption  FreeSpace      
A:                      
B:       1098552672256  
C:       40824201216    
D:                      
E:       1042498560000  
F:       40222941184
```

The output of the original script created file was `ECHO is off.`. The output with the text file created by me was `F:` which is the correct output because we can't use the system drive `C:`.

So I tried `echo END OF FILE>>getDiskInfo.txt` and it added the line `久⁄䙏䘠䱉൅` to the script created file, but the same command added `END OF FILE` to my text file. I'm completely lost on this one.

Do you have any suggestions or probable solutions?

Comment: [See here for an explanation as to what's interfering, as well as the resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34695095/12343998)

Comment: wow thanks, this can be really helpful, i'll look into it later on and come back to share my results.
thanks for the comment :)

Comment: @T3RR0R i've been messing with it for a while but i just can't seem to get it working. i guess it's time to take a break from this stuff

Comment: If you have the option, search out a powershell solution. It's a lot more robust and doesn't suffer so many of the design shortcomings Batch does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple problems to solve for this task to get the drive letter of a (local) hard disk drive with less than one [TiB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TiB) (1 099 511 627 776 bytes) free space which is not the system drive.

### 1. Character encoding of WMIC output

**WMIC** outputs data always with [character encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding) [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) [Little Endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) with [byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) abbreviated as **UTF-16LE+BOM**.

So the data output

```
Caption  FreeSpace      
A:                      
B:       1098552672256  
C:       40824201216    
D:                      
E:       1042498560000  
F:       40222941184
```

is as byte stream with byte offset left to `:` and ASCII representation right to `;`:

```
0000h: FF FE 43 00 61 00 70 00 74 00 69 00 6F 00 6E 00 ; ÿþC.a.p.t.i.o.n.
0010h: 20 00 20 00 46 00 72 00 65 00 65 00 53 00 70 00 ;  . .F.r.e.e.S.p.
0020h: 61 00 63 00 65 00 20 00 20 00 20 00 20 00 20 00 ; a.c.e. . . . . .
0030h: 20 00 0D 00 0A 00 41 00 3A 00 20 00 20 00 20 00 ;  .....A.:. . . .
0040h: 20 00 20 00 20 00 20 00 20 00 20 00 20 00 20 00 ;  . . . . . . . .
0050h: 20 00 20 00 20 00 20 00 20 00 20 00 20 00 20 00 ;  . . . . . . . .
0060h: 20 00 20 00 20 00 0D 00 0A 00 42 00 3A 00 20 00 ;  . . .....B.:. .
0070h: 20 00 20 00 20 00 20 00 20 00 20 00 31 00 30 00 ;  . . . . . .1.0.
0080h: 39 00 38 00 35 00 35 00 32 00 36 00 37 00 32 00 ; 9.8.5.5.2.6.7.2.
0090h: 32 00 35 00 36 00 20 00 20 00 0D 00 0A 00 43 00 ; 2.5.6. . .....C.
00a0h: 3A 00 20 00 20 00 20 00 20 00 20 00 20 00 20 00 ; :. . . . . . . .
00b0h: 34 00 30 00 38 00 32 00 34 00 32 00 30 00 31 00 ; 4.0.8.2.4.2.0.1.
00c0h: 32 00 31 00 36 00 20 00 20 00 20 00 20 00 0D 00 ; 2.1.6. . . . ...
00d0h: 0A 00 44 00 3A 00 20 00 20 00 20 00 20 00 20 00 ; ..D.:. . . . . .
00e0h: 20 00 20 00 20 00 20 00 20 00 20 00 20 00 20 00 ;  . . . . . . . .
00f0h: 20 00 20 00 20 00 20 00 20 00 20 00 20 00 20 00 ;  . . . . . . . .
0100h: 20 00 0D 00 0A 00 45 00 3A 00 20 00 20 00 20 00 ;  .....E.:. . . .
0110h: 20 00 20 00 20 00 20 00 31 00 30 00 34 00 32 00 ;  . . . .1.0.4.2.
0120h: 34 00 39 00 38 00 35 00 36 00 30 00 30 00 30 00 ; 4.9.8.5.6.0.0.0.
0130h: 30 00 20 00 20 00 0D 00 0A 00 46 00 3A 00 20 00 ; 0. . .....F.:. .
0140h: 20 00 20 00 20 00 20 00 20 00 20 00 34 00 30 00 ;  . . . . . .4.0.
0150h: 32 00 32 00 32 00 39 00 34 00 31 00 31 00 38 00 ; 2.2.2.9.4.1.1.8.
0160h: 34 00 20 00 20 00 20 00 20 00 0D 00 0A 00       ; 4. . . . .....
```

But Windows command processor expects a one byte per character encoding using the [code page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page) as output on running in an opened command prompt window the command `chcp`. The code page depends on which country is configured for the account used to run the command process processing the batch file.

The command line `chcp 65001>nul` to change to Unicode encoding [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) is of no help here.

Processing UTF-16LE encoded output with **FOR** directly cause troubles as documented on Stack Overflow multiple times, see for example [How to correct variable overwriting misbehavior when parsing output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24961755/)

A solution would be to redirect the output of **WMIC** into a temporary file, output this temporary file to handle **STDOUT** (standard output) of a command process started in background with `%ComSpec% /c` using the command **TYPE** with capturing this output by the command process executing the batch file, process this ASCII output line by line, and finally delete the temporary file.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe LOGICALDISK GET Caption,FreeSpace >"%TEMP%\%~n0.tmp"
if not exist "%TEMP%\%~n0.tmp" goto EndBatch

for /F "skip=1 tokens=1,2" %%I in ('type "%TEMP%\%~n0.tmp"') do echo %%I %%J
del "%TEMP%\%~n0.tmp"

:EndBatch
endlocal
```

In this case **FOR** processes the ASCII byte stream:

```
000h: 43 61 70 74 69 6F 6E 20 20 46 72 65 65 53 70 61 ; Caption  FreeSpa
010h: 63 65 20 20 20 20 20 20 0D 0A 41 3A 20 20 20 20 ; ce      ..A:    
020h: 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 ;                 
030h: 20 20 0D 0A 42 3A 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 31 30 39 ;   ..B:       109
040h: 38 35 35 32 36 37 32 32 35 36 20 20 0D 0A 43 3A ; 8552672256  ..C:
050h: 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 34 30 38 32 34 32 30 31 32 ;        408242012
060h: 31 36 20 20 20 20 0D 0A 44 3A 20 20 20 20 20 20 ; 16    ..D:      
070h: 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 ;                 
080h: 0D 0A 45 3A 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 31 30 34 32 34 ; ..E:       10424
090h: 39 38 35 36 30 30 30 30 20 20 0D 0A 46 3A 20 20 ; 98560000  ..F:  
0a0h: 20 20 20 20 20 34 30 32 32 32 39 34 31 31 38 34 ;      40222941184
0b0h: 20 20 20 20 0D 0A                               ;     ..
```

But it is in general always better to avoid the usage of a temporary file as there is never the guarantee that the temporary file can be created at all during the execution of the batch file.

### 2. System drive is not always C:

Windows is installed by default on drive C: and so the system drive is `C:`. But Windows can be installed also to a different drive in which case the system drive is not `C:`. Any code depending on default data instead of using the appropriate data is a not good written code.

There is predefined the [Windows environment variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Windows) `SystemDrive` with the drive letter and the colon of the drive on which active Windows is installed. The environment variable `SystemRoot` contains the path to the Windows directory which contains the directory `System32` with all executables from the [Windows Commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/windows-commands) list which are not internal commands of `cmd.exe`.

All those system environment variables can be seen with their values on opening a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window and running `set system`. Running just `set` outputs all environment variables with their values defined for the current user account.

### 3. Integer value range is limited to 32-bit signed integer

The Windows command processor `cmd.exe` uses always only 32-bit signed integer on evaluation of an arithmetic expression with `set /A` and for comparing integer values with command **IF** on using the operators `EQU`, `NEQ`, `LSS`, `LEQ`, `GTR`, `GEQ`.

Therefore the integer value range is `−2147483648` to `2147483647`. So maximum is one byte less than 2 GiB. The value is `1099511627776` requires 64-bit integer value range not supported by `cmd.exe`.

BTW: `if [%%Y] neq []` is never a good comparison because of `[` and `]` have no special meaning for Windows command processor and `neq` results here first in the approach to convert the left string into a 32-bit signed integer value which fails because of `[` is an invalid character for an integer value and therefore running next a string comparison with condition being true if the string comparison returns not `0`, i.e. the compared strings are not equal. Better would be `if not "%%Y" == ""` which runs directly and more safely a string comparison on not equal strings. See [Symbol equivalent to NEQ, LSS, GTR, etc. in Windows batch files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47386323/3074564) for details on how command **IF** executes a string comparison.

### 4. Solution to get drives with less than one TiB free space

It is a good idea to read the documentation of a class of which properties are accessed using the [Windows Management Instrumentation Command-line](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/wmic) utility. This is here the [Win32_LogicalDisk class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-logicaldisk).

There is in addition to `FreeSpace` of type `uint64` and `DeviceID` of type `string` instead of `Caption` perhaps also useful the property `DriveType` of type `uint32` to filter out drives of wrong type in addition to drives with too much free space and the system drive by using a `where` clause on `wmic` execution.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "UsableDrive="
for /F "skip=1 tokens=1,2" %%I in ('""%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe" LOGICALDISK where (DriveType=3 and FreeSpace^<1099511627776 and DeviceID!='C:') GET DeviceID,FreeSpace 2>nul"') do (
    echo Drive %%I has %%J free bytes.
    if not defined UsableDrive set "UsableDrive=%%I"
)
if defined UsableDrive echo Selected drive %UsableDrive%
endlocal
```

Important to know here is that **FOR** starts in background with `%ComSpec% /c` one more command process with the command line specified within `'` appended as additional arguments. For that reason the command line with **WMIC** must fulfill the Windows command processor requirements described by help output on running `cmd /?` in a command prompt window on being in total three times parsed.

The first parsing is done by `cmd.exe` processing the batch file before executing command **FOR**.

The second parsing is done by `cmd.exe` instance on starting it in background by the `cmd.exe` instance processing the batch file with the following command line on Windows installed to `C:\Windows`.

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c ""C:\WINDOWS\System32\wbem\wmic.exe" LOGICALDISK where (DriveType=3 and FreeSpace^<1099511627776 and DeviceID!='C:') GET DeviceID,FreeSpace 2>nul"
```

The third parsing is done by the background command process before executing `wmic.exe`. The operator `<` in `where` clause must be interpreted as literal character and not as redirection operator which is the reason why `<` is escaped with `^` to run `wmic.exe` finally with:

```
"C:\Windows\System32\wbem\wmic.exe" LOGICALDISK where (DriveType=3 and FreeSpace<1099511627776 and DeviceID!='C:') GET DeviceID,FreeSpace
```

**WMIC** filters out with `DriveType=3` all network drives, floppy disk drives, CD and DVD drives and other removable drives, RAM disks, etc. Hard disks connected to the computer using an external USB port or an eSATA port are not filtered out because of those drives have also value `3` for the drive type. Windows cannot determine if a hard disk is mounted inside the casing of the computer or outside. So a **local** hard disk is any hard disk connected to the computer, internal and external hard disks.

The system drive is filtered out with second condition `DeviceID!='%SystemDrive%'`.

The last condition `FreeSpace<1099511627776` results in ignoring all drives with 1 TiB or more free space.

So the list is reduced already to those drives which fulfill all three conditions.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `cmd /?`
- `del /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`
- `type /?`
- `wmic /?`
- `wmic logicaldisk /?`
- `wmic logicaldisk get /?`

See also the Microsoft article about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for an explanation of `>` and `2>nul`.

Comment: thanks for the answer, it was very informative and helpful. and for your 2. point, yeah i'm fully aware of that, but in the system which i'm working with, it's always c:, so i figured why not just filter it that way

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirements correctly, the following, much shorter, single line [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file), should output only the usable drives, i.e. which, are not your system drive, and have less than 1 TB of free disk space.

```batch-file
@(For /F "Tokens=1-2" %%G In ('""%__AppDir__%wbem\WMIC.exe" LogicalDisk Where (DeviceID !='%SystemDrive%' And FreeSpace ^<'1000000000000') Get DeviceID,FreeSpace 2>NUL|"%__AppDir%find.exe" ":""')Do @Set "_=              %%H"&SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion&Echo %%G   !_:~-14!&EndLocal)&Pause
```

*As you did not explain in your question, what you were doing with the data retrieved, I have simply printed them to the console window in a similar format to your original `getDiskInfo.txt`, (I even right aligned the bytes column just for fun!).*