# How to return the letters of all partitions on a drive in CMD/Batch?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

My goal is to retrieve the letters of every partition and loop through those to complete another task on each partition using that letter as a variable. Currently right now I have...

```
wmic logicaldisk get caption
```

which returns...

```
Caption  
C:       
D:
```

Now how do I take that output, and take only C, then D, as a variable for a batch script?

Thank you very much, appreciate the help.

Comment: ***Show Code***

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Batch WMIC redirecting output and wrapping into variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12964631/batch-wmic-redirecting-output-and-wrapping-into-variable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probable code example:

```
@Echo Off
For /F "Skip=1 Delims=:" %%A In ('WMIC LogicalDisk Get Caption') Do Echo=%%A:
Timeout -1
```

Change `Echo=` to an appropriate command as necessary.