# Retrieve local area connection name and change it with batch

Tags: batch-file

I know how to retrieve the active connection and change a local area connection name but I would like to know how to do them in one script, i.e. retrieve the active Local area connection name and change it to LAN.

To retrieve current active connections:

```
wmic.exe nic where "NetConnectionStatus=2" get NetConnectionID |more +1
```

Change network name to:

```
NetSh interface set interface name="Ethernet" newname="LAN"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is the [`for /F` loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html), which is capable of capturing the output of a command:

```cmd
for /F "tokens=1* delims==" %%J in ('
    wmic NIC where "NetConnectionStatus=2" get NetConnectionID /VALUE
') do (
    for /F "delims=" %%I in ("%%K") do (
        netsh interface set interface name="%%I" newname="LAN"
    )
)
```

The inner `for /F` loop here is needed to avoid artefacts (like orphaned carriage-return characters) from the conversion of [`wmic`](https://ss64.com/nt/wmic.html)'s Unicode text to ASCII/ANSI text by the outer `for /F` (see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42199181) of mine).

*I also changed the output format of `wmic` by the `/VALUE` option as recommended by user [Compo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6738015) in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56773703/retrieve-local-area-connection-name-and-change-it-with-batch/56775207#comment100109369_56775207), which avoids trouble with potential trailing <kbd>SPACEs</kbd>.*

---

Note that the `wmic` query might return more than one adapter, so perhaps you want to extend the `where` clause to avoid that, like this, for example:

```cmd
for /F "tokens=1* delims==" %%J in ('
    wmic NIC where "NetConnectionStatus=2 and NetConnectionID like '%%Ethernet%%'" get NetConnectionID /VALUE
') do (
    for /F "delims=" %%I in ("%%K") do (
        netsh interface set interface name="%%I" newname="LAN"
    )
)
```

The `%%` in the batch file represents one literal `%`, and a `%` is a wildcard in `where` clauses, so the above code only returns items with `Ethernet` in their names (in a case-insensitive manner).

---

To guarantee that only one item is touched by `netsh`, you could simply use [`goto`](https://ss64.com/nt/goto.html) in the `for /F` loops to break them:

```cmd
for /F "tokens=1* delims==" %%J in ('
    wmic NIC where "NetConnectionStatus=2" get NetConnectionID /VALUE
') do (
    for /F "delims=" %%I in ("%%K") do (
        netsh interface set interface name="%%I" newname="LAN"
        goto :NEXT
    )
)
:NEXT
```

---

*Reference: [Win32_NetworkAdapter class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/CIMWin32Prov/win32-networkadapter)*

Comment: Just to note that using WMIC's default tabular format would likely append one or more spaces to the end of the returned string. This would mean that you would effectively be passing `name="Local Area Connection  "`, which may as a result fail. I would suggest therefore `@For /F "Tokens=1*Delims==" %%A In ('WMIC NIC Where "NetConnectionStatus='2'" Get NetConnectionID /Format:List 2^>NUL')Do @For /F "Tokens=*" %%C In
 ("%%B")Do @NetSH Interface Set interface name="%%C"…`. *You could also replace `/Format:List` with `/Value`.*

Comment: Thanks, @Compo, you're absolutely right, I totally forgot about the trailing _spaces_; see my edited answer...