# How to add empty space using batch script?

Tags: string, batch-file

Is there any way to loop a text file which will add a EMPTY **SPACE** in front of each line?

commit.txt

```
commit c9bee
Merge: 7db
Author: TOM
Date:   Fri Mar 13

Author: TIM
```

output.txt

```
 commit c9bee
 Merge: 7db
 Author: TOM
 Date:   Fri Mar 13

 Author: TIM
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one solution:

```
for /f "delims=" %i in (file) do @echo  %i
```

Note that you must double the percents if you use this in a script (as opposed to interactive usage).

Comment: thanks for quick reply, your one liner works well. But, if there are any empty line in between, it says "ECHO is on."

Comment: for /f "delims=" %i in (file) do @echo.  %i     will fix empty line issue.

Answer (score 1):

-Editing here to mention escaping the space is not required, you can use `ECHO  1` to get a (space)1.

Try escaping the space using `^`

For example:

> C:\Scripts>echo ^ string
>
> string
>
> C:\Scripts>echo string
>
> string

-edit, this is what happens when you rush and don't read the question fully!

Try this:

> C:\Scripts>for /f %a in (input.txt) do echo ^ %a

```
C:\Scripts>echo  test1
 test1
C:\Scripts>echo  test2
 test2
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but i think syntax should be --> for /f "delims=" %a in (commit.txt) do echo ^ %a. For empty line i'm having same issue "ECHO is on." seen.

Comment: for /f "delims=" %i in (file) do @echo.  %i     will fix empty line issue.

Comment: Try this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24289027/4317867) which uses `FindStr /v` to skip blank lines.

Answer (score 1):

try this. This "overwrites" the original file.If you want to keep the name as output.txt just comment out the call to Overwriteoriginal

```
@echo off

REM makes sure the user passed in a file name
if [%1]==[] (
    echo Must pass in a file name
) else (
    Call:AddSpaceToEveryLine %1

    Call:OverwriteOriginal %1

    echo processed %1
)

GoTo:EOF

:OverwriteOriginal 
    REM overwrites original file with spaced file
    del %1

    rename output.txt %1
GoTo:EOF

:AddSpaceToEveryLine
    REM there is actually one space after the equals sign
    set space= 
    for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (%1) do (
      echo %space%%%a >> output.txt
    )
GoTo:EOF
```

Comment: thanks for quick reply. But, if there are any empty line in between, it says "ECHO is off."

Answer (score 0):

It can be done very easily and you don't need a for loop for it.  Just declare a variable and and at the end of of your code just to do echo with the declared variable few times to your output file.  In this case, I am sending to a file called  `c:\sample.txt`.  Here is an example:

```
@echo off

set blank=

:: Your main code goes here

echo. %blank% >> c:\sample.txt
echo. %blank% >> c:\sample.txt
echo. %blank% >> c:\sample.txt

echo. Author: TIM >> c:\sample.txt
```