# getting windows product key from bios

Tags: batch-file, wmic

I'm attempting to make a batch script to pull the windows product key from BIOS so the computer can be properly activated in a production environment.

The command I am running to get the key is `wmic path SoftwareLicensingService get OA3xOriginalProductKey > text.txt`

which creates a text file called text.txt which contains this:

```
OA3xOriginalProductKey         
xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx
```

(Note some random spaces in there after each line)
The problem is I need JUST the `xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx` part, but I am having a terrible time doing that.

I have tried the following:

`for /F "skip=10 delims=" %%i in (text.txt) do echo %%i`

`for /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%G in ('findstr /n "^" text.txt') do if %%G equ 2 echo %%H`

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (text.txt) do call :processline %%a

:processline
echo line=%*
```

and last but not least

```
for /F "tokens=2" %%i in (text.txt) do echo %%i %%j %%k
```

As I said I am having a terrible time and am very much a noob with for /f - I have no idea where I am going wrong or what to do.

Comment: Related: [Skipping last empty line of WMIC command output in batch](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37708060)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `for` to get the output of a command.

```
@echo off
For /f "tokens=2 delims=," %%a in ('wmic path SoftwareLicensingService get OA3xOriginalProductKey^,VLRenewalInterval /value /format:csv') do set key=%%a
echo %key%
```

Using another `wmic` token (here `VLRenewalInterval`) is one of several methods to get rid of the ugly wmic line endings (the desired token has no line ending).