# Sum up command output by skipping blank/null values in Windows batch file for loop

Tags: batch-file

I want run a command and sum up the output in a batch file. Here is the code:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET NoOfCores=0
FOR /F "skip=1 USEBACKQ" %%G IN (`wmic cpu get NumberOfLogicalProcessors`) DO (
    IF NOT "%%G" == "" (
        SET /A NoOfCores = !NoOfCores! + %%G
    )
)
echo NoOfCores:%NoOfCores%
ENDLOCAL
```

When I run this batch file I am getting correct output along with an ERROR:

```
Missing operand.
NoOfCores:8
```

When I run command `wmic cpu get NumberOfLogicalProcessors` manually, I am getting output like this:

```
NumberOfLogicalProcessors
4
4
```

Can someone please tell me how to skip the last blank line in the output?

I have referred several articles about checking blank/null values in IF condition but none seem to be working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Output of **wmic** is encoded in UTF-16 Little Endian which causes troubles on parsing by command **FOR**.

The command **FOR** interprets the end of the file on conversion from Unicode to single byte encoded text as **carriage return** *carriage return line feed*. The erroneous **carriage return** makes the last line not empty. In the provided batch code this results in `IF NOT "%%G" == ""` being true as loop variable contains a carriage return. But command **SET** on evaluating the arithmetic expression interprets the carriage return as whitespace character and therefore there is indeed missing the second operand on addition.

But all this can't be seen on running the batch file in a command prompt window with `@echo on` in first line as on write to console window every carriage return is removed by stream writer.

For more details see the answers on [How to correct variable overwriting misbehavior when parsing output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24961755/).

One workaround is to first redirect output of **wmic** into a temporary file and use command **TYPE** within **FOR** to process the lines as command **TYPE** makes a better job on conversion from Unicode to OEM than command **FOR**. The temporary file is deleted after processing the lines.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe cpu get NumberOfLogicalProcessors >"%TEMP%\NumberOfLogicalProcessors.tmp"
set "NoOfCores=0"
for /F "skip=1" %%G in ('type "%TEMP%\NumberOfLogicalProcessors.tmp"') do set /A NoOfCores+=%%G
del "%TEMP%\NumberOfLogicalProcessors.tmp"
echo NoOfCores: %NoOfCores%
endlocal
```

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `del /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`
- `type /?`
- `wmic cpu get /?`

Answer (score 1):

[Mofi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37959864) gives a great explanation of what is going on here and provides a solution for that.

There is an even simpler approach though: placing another `for /F` loop to parse the output of the first one a second time to get rid of the orphaned carriage-return characters. This is the easiest and most versatile solution for correct parsing of Unicode text.

So here is the code I would use:

```
@echo off
set /A NoOfCores=0
for /F "skip=1" %%G in ('wmic cpu get NumberOfLogicalProcessors') do (
    for /F %%H in ("%%G") do (
        set /A NoOfCores+=%%G
    )
)
echo NoOfCores: %NoOfCores%
```

This method is credited to [dbenham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1012053/dbenham) -- see his answer to [Why is the FOR /f loop in this batch script evaluating a blank line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14658784) and also his external article [WMIC and FOR /F : A fix for the trailing <CR> problem](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4266).