# Set Variable to value of command

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I need to set the value of WMIC COMPUTERSYSTEM GET MODEL /Value to a variable.  when I run this command I get the results below.  Why do I get the extra blank lines?

```
U:\>for /f "delims=" %i in ('WMIC COMPUTERSYSTEM GET MODEL /Value') do set output=%i
 :\>set output=
 :\>set output=
 :\>set output=Model=HP ProDesk 600 G1 SFF
 :\>set output=
 :\>set output=
 :\>set output=
```

Comment: @jeb, I considered the missing drive letters `U` in the output as copy-and-paste errors, that is why I (re-)inserted them (hastily); the true output on the console would normally also contain empty lines between each adjacent echoes; anyway, I asked the OP to show us the true output...

Comment: @aschipfl I tested it before I edited, as I thought too at first that he simply missed the `U:>`, but I was wrong

Comment: Ah, yes, @jeb, it seems that every line is ended with a carriage-return and a space...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a problem of the WMIC output, that contains `carriage return` characters.
Therefore the empty lines aren't removed, as they are not completely empty.

The carriage returns are also responsible for the strange output of `:>` instead of `U:>`, as the carriage return first moves the cursor to `POS1` and then a space deletes the `U`.

With an extra FOR/F you can strip the carriage return characters

```
for /f "delims=" %i in ('WMIC COMPUTERSYSTEM GET MODEL /Value') do @(
    for /F "delims=" %X in ("%i") do set output=%X
)
```

Btw. Normally you want such an expression in a batch file, not at the command line.
Then you have to convert it to

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('WMIC COMPUTERSYSTEM GET MODEL /Value') do (
    for /F "delims=" %%X in ("%%i") do set output=%%X
)
```

Comment: To be more exact, I believe the problem is due to WMIC outputting in UTF-8 while internal commands expect ANSI. Many posts on SO address that subject. That said, @jeb's solution works just fine.

Comment: Yes, you are right, the output is UTF-8, that causes the carriage return problem, as the bytes are `00 CR 00 LF` instead of `CR LF`

Answer (score 0):

> Why do I get the extra blank lines?

Because `WMIC` prints those empty lines in its output, and ["FOR /F processing of a text file consists of reading the file, **one line of text at a time** and then breaking the line up into individual items"](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) (emphasis mine).

So even if you don't define any delimers, each line still is processed individually.

If you don't need that `Model=` in your output, you can use this:

`for /f "delims== tokens=2" %i in ('WMIC COMPUTERSYSTEM GET MODEL /Value') do set output=%i`

Comment: I tried the 'do set output=%output%%i'  and it is not setting the value I got
U:\>echo %output%
%output%

U:\>echo %output%%i
%output%%i

Comment: @JohnRing That is an other question, it has nothing todo with the empty lines, you should modify your question

Answer (score 0):

The `wmic` command produces Unicode output which `for /F` has problems with, so unwanted artefacts remain. In fact those are orphaned carriage-return characters. The best and most flexible method to overcome this is to nest another `for /F` loop so that the `wmic` output is parsed twice.

The following command line is typed directly into the console, the respective output is also shown:

```
U:\>for /F "delims=" %I in ('wmic ComputerSystem GET Model /VALUE') do @for /F "delims=" %L in ("%I") do set "output=%L"

U:\>set "output=Model=HP ProDesk 600 G1 SFF"

U:\>
```

To use the above command line in a batch file you need to double the percent signs:

```
@echo off
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('wmic ComputerSystem GET Model /VALUE') do (
    for /F "delims=" %%L in ("%%I") do set "output=%%L"
)
echo %output%
```

To strip off the `Model=` prefix from the value of the variable `output`, change the script to this:

```
@echo off
for /F "tokens=1,* delims==" %%I in ('wmic ComputerSystem GET Model /VALUE') do (
    for /F "delims=" %%L in ("%%J") do set "output=%%L"
)
echo %output%
```

---

The double-parsing method is actually credited to [dbenham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1012053/dbenham) -- see his answer to [Why is the FOR /f loop in this batch script evaluating a blank line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14658784) and also his external article [WMIC and FOR /F : A fix for the trailing <CR> problem](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4266).

Answer (score 0):

As others have already mentioned, the issue is due to the Unicode output of WMIC.
In your case, you can still keep everything on a single line with the following command:

```
for /f "delims=" %i in ('WMIC COMPUTERSYSTEM GET MODEL /Value^|findstr /i "MODEL"') do @(set output=%i)
```