# If statement based on result of WMI query

Tags: batch-file, wmi

Really struggling with `WMI` syntax any help would be much appreciated

I have 2 reg keys and I want to run a `WMI` query to determine if my PC is a laptop or a desktop. Then, I want to import a reg key based on the result. If desktop, import `desktop.reg`, If laptop, import `laptop.reg`.

The `WMI` query that I have been using is:

```
wmic path Win32_PhysicalMemory get FormFactor
```

and an ouput of `12 = SODIMM` memory, so a laptop. How can implement the following?:

```
IF "formfactor"="12" ( do this ) else ( do that )
```

Point in the right direction much appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the result of a command in a variable in windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/108439/how-do-i-get-the-result-of-a-command-in-a-variable-in-windows)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set Variable to value of command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38742917/set-variable-to-value-of-command)

Comment: I see no reason not to use, `Wmic Path Win32_PhysicalMemory Where "FormFactor='12'" Get...`, _although I doubt that this is the best way to determine a notebook from a desktop_.

Comment: @Compo you are right, i have since switched to wmic path Win32_ComputerSystem get PCSystemType where 1 is desktop, 2 is laptop. this is more consistent as we have some all in one system that have small memory type. but the code for script is the same just swap a small part

Comment: For more accuracy you could also take a look at, `Win32_SystemEnclosure`.

Answer (score 3):

Although a `for /f` loop (as shown by aschipfl) is the correct method to get a commands output to a variable, it's not really needed here:

```
wmic path Win32_PhysicalMemory get FormFactor|find "12" >nul && goto :Laptop || goto :desktop
goto :eof
:desktop
  echo This is a desktop
  goto :eof
:laptop
  echo this is a laptop
  goto :eof
```

Comment: I was about to implement this method (actually based on `findstr`) into my answer, but you were faster, obviously...

Comment: thank you so much!  2 different approaches, both approaches have improved my knowledge. many thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use a [`for /F` loop](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) loop to capture the output of your `wmic` command line:

```cmd
for /F "skip=1" %%E in ('
    wmic path Win32_PhysicalMemory get FormFactor
') do for /F %%F in ("%%E") do set "FF=%%F"
if %FF% equ 12 (
    echo FormFactor is 12.
) else (
    echo FormFactor is not 12.
)
```

The second `for /F` loop in this example prevents artefacts (like orphaned carriage-return characters) from converting the Unicode output of `wmic` to ANSI by `for /F.

If there are more than one memory module, the `for /F` loop is iterating over all of them, so the interim variable `FF` actually contains the form factor of the lastly iterated one.

If you want to execute the code in a command prompt window rather than in a batch file, regard that you have to replace `%%E` and `%%F` by `%E` and `%F`, respectively.

---

You can let the [`wmic` command](http://ss64.com/nt/wmic.html) do the filtering using a `where` clause:

```cmd
wmic path Win32_PhysicalMemory where FormFactor=12 get FormFactor
```

Then use the [`find` command](http://ss64.com/nt/find.html) to check whether or not there are matching items, like this:

```cmd
2> nul wmic path Win32_PhysicalMemory where FormFactor=12 get FormFactor /VALUE | > nul find "=" && (
    echo FormFactor is 12.
) || (
    echo FormFactor is not 12.
)
```

The `/VALUE` switch changes the output of `wmic` to something like `FormFactor=12`; `find` is then used to find returned lines containing `=`. Due to the said filtering by `where` there is no matching output at all if there is no such expected form factor. The [`&&` and `||` operators](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) are conditional operators that react on the returned exit code of `find`.

---

Anyway, determining the form factor of the memory modules is probably not the most reliable method to find out whether your computer is a laptop (mobile); so as you already mentioned in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53483579#comment93839215_53483579), the [`Win32_ComputerSystem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/cimwin32prov/win32-computersystem) class is a more suitable one:

```cmd
2> nul wmic path Win32_ComputerSystem where PCSystemType=2 get PCSystemType /VALUE | > nul find "=" && (
    echo The computer is a laptop.
) || (
    echo The computer is not a laptop.
)
```

Comment: thank you so much for your reply. I think for /F is exactly what i'm looking for

with regards to your example, i can't seem to get it to work. should i just be able to run it as a batch script?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot about skipping the header `FormFactor` of the output and the Unicode-to-ANSI conversion issue -- see my edit...

Comment: `if %%F equ 12 (` is out of any `FOR` scope. Should be `if %FF% equ 12 (`

Comment: Oh yes, @JosefZ, thank you; this was kind of a typo; originally I planned to place the `if` condition directly into the loop body, but I decided to change that, because it would be executed multiple times in case there are more than one memory module; I assume that they are all of the same form factor though...