# wmic works well in cmd but not work in batch file

Tags: batch-file, wmic

i try write something to get the hdd index in a batch script, the command below in comand prompt works well

```
wmic diskdrive where "model like '%st%' and size > 300000000000" get index,model
```

it returns

```
Index  Model
1      ST1000DM010-2EP102
```

but when i use it inside batch script, it return 'no instances available':

```
@echo off

for /f "usebackq skip=1" %%a in (`wmic diskdrive where "model like '%st%' and size > 300000000000" get index`) do echo %%a

pause
```

result of script

```
No Instance(s) Available.
```

by the way, if there is a better way to get the hdd index in batch script.

---

```
wmic diskdrive where "model like '%st%' and size > 300000000000" get /format:csv
```

@Compo, The result of the command is showed as follows

```
Node,Availability,BytesPerSector,Capabilities,CapabilityDescriptions,Caption,CompressionMethod,ConfigManagerErrorCode,ConfigManagerUserConfig,CreationClassName,DefaultBlockSize,Description,DeviceID,ErrorCleared,ErrorDescription,ErrorMethodology,FirmwareRevision,Index,InstallDate,InterfaceType,LastErrorCode,Manufacturer,MaxBlockSize,MaxMediaSize,MediaLoaded,MediaType,MinBlockSize,Model,Name,NeedsCleaning,NumberOfMediaSupported,Partitions,PNPDeviceID,PowerManagementCapabilities,PowerManagementSupported,SCSIBus,SCSILogicalUnit,SCSIPort,SCSITargetId,SectorsPerTrack,SerialNumber,Signature,Size,Status,StatusInfo,SystemCreationClassName,SystemName,TotalCylinders,TotalHeads,TotalSectors,TotalTracks,TracksPerCylinder
W0400966,,512,{3;4},{Random Access;Supports Writing},ST1000DM010-2EP102,,0,FALSE,Win32_DiskDrive,,Disk drive,\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE1,,,,CC46,1,,IDE,,(Standard disk drives),,,TRUE,Fixed hard disk media,,ST1000DM010-2EP102,\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE1,,,3,SCSI\DISK&amp;VEN_ST1000DM&amp;PROD_010-2EP102\4&amp;BFDEFCD&amp;0&amp;000100,,,0,0,0,1,63,            ZN1PYMST,3140447416,1000202273280,OK,,Win32_ComputerSystem,W0400966,121601,255,1953520065,31008255,255
```

Comment: Works fine for me. Is `%st%` properly defined in your script?

Comment: It's a batch file, you need to escape your percent wildcards! ```'%%st%%'```.

Comment: If you explain what exactly you need the drive index for, and show us the output from ```WMIC.exe DiskDrive Get /Format:CSV``` we may be able to assist you further.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set Variable to value of command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38742917/set-variable-to-value-of-command) Specifically, since `wmic` uses UTF-16 line endings, you either need to pipe the results to `findstr` or run it through a second `for` loop.

Comment: That's what I figured. Is it properly defined in the script? Does the script work when you use the string directly (without using a variable)?

Comment: @Compo escape percent wildcards '%%st%%' not work for me

Comment: @Stephan when i set st='ST1000DM010-2EP102' it works indeed, but I want to use fuzzy matching to match the model of hdd

Comment: You can tell me that if you like @Jacky, but you are most certainly wrong. I can guarantee the the fix for your working Command Prompt version in a batch file, is what I told you! However, as we now know the string you were trying to match, I would say you definitely wanted to use ```@%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe DiskDrive Where "Model Like 'ST%%' And Size > 300000000000" Get Index, Model```, because you are only needing to wildcard the trailing characters, leading ones don't exist.

Comment: However, as you've completely changed your code, to run that within a `For /F` loop, it would look like this ```In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe DiskDrive Where "Model Like 'ST%%' And Size > 300000000000" Get Index^, Model 2^>NUL') Do```.

Comment: @Compo it really works! The difference between command prompt and batch file does confuse me a lot, thank you very much for your patience in explaining

Comment: when you `set st='ST1000DM010-2EP102'`, what do you think `'%st%'` expands to? (Tip: `''ST1000DM010-2EP102''`)

Comment: @Stephan, Compo is right, i just want to wildcard the substring in the model

Comment: I reopened this question, because it was closed as a duplicate of a problem which was nothing to do with the reported issue. The issue, which was subsequently confirmed by the OP, was about the escaping of literal percent characters. Their use of `%st%` was not a variable for expansion, it was a wmi 'like" operator pattern. Isolating a substring of a commands output was only a secondary problem, which only became known after the OP later edited their question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first submitted, and working Command Prompt example, you are using a WMI LIKE Operator, `%` which is signifies 0 or more string characters.

A percent character `%` is a special character in a batch file, so any literal would need to be escaped. The escape character for a percent is another percent.

Therefore in order to reproduce that Command Prompt code, in a batch file, you would use:

```bash
wmic diskdrive where "model like '%%st%%' and size > 300000000000" get index,model
```

However, the Model substring you are wanting to match actually begins with `ST`, it doesn't include the two characters `st` in any position. For that reason your code should have been using `ST%%` as your pattern.

```bash
%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe DiskDrive Where "Model Like 'ST%%' And Size > 300000000000" Get Index, Model
```

Subsequently, you edited your question to show us that you weren't really wanting to reproduce the Command Prompt code, but wanting to run it as a `For` parenthesized command. In order to do that in your batch file, you would have needed to escape the unquoted comma:

```bash
… In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe DiskDrive Where "Model Like 'ST%%' And Size > 300000000000" Get Index^, Model 2^>NUL') Do …
```

You will note above, that should the WMIC command report `No Instance(s) Available.`, I decided to send that output to the NUL device, (which subsequently passes nothing through to the `Do` portion of the loop).

It became clear that you did not want to report the Model string at all, but isolate a specific substring of its output, i.e. just the Index number. For that, I would advise that you define a variable using the returned value.

```bash
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

Set "Index="
For /F "Tokens=2 Delims==" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe
 DiskDrive Where "Model Like 'ST%%' And Size > 300000000000" Get Index
 /Value 2^>NUL') Do For %%H In (%%G) Do Set "Index=%%H"
If Not Defined Index GoTo :EOF

Rem Your code continues below here.
Echo Your Disk Index is %Index%
Pause
```

I have included a couple of lines below the `Rem`ark, for demonstration purposes only. Feel free to replace those as needed for your specific task.