# Removing Last Empty Entry After Getting Drive List - Batch Script

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, wmic

Here is my batch script which gives you the list of hard drive letters:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "skip=1 tokens=1,2 delims=: " %%a in ('WMIC LogicalDisk Where "DriveType='3'" Get DeviceID') do (
   set "_DRIVE.LETTERS.USED=!_DRIVE.LETTERS.USED!%%a:\ ; "
)
echo %_DRIVE.LETTERS.USED%
```

My expected output is: `C:\ ; D:\` But it will print `C:\ ; D:\ ; :\ ;`

How to remove last extra `:\ ;`?

Comment: Filter for the relevant lines: `...  Get DeviceID^|find ":"') do ...` to get rid of empty entries and `echo %_DRIVE.LETTERS.USED:~0,-3%` to delete the last space/semicolon/space.

Comment: @Stephan Thank you works great. please submit it as the answer. and could you please tell me how to solve this one in short? `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59164308/counter-will-not-add-inside-a-loop-batch-script?noredirect=1#comment104552640_59164308`

Comment: I commented on your other question. Interesting, you *did*  use delayed expansion here, but *forgot* it there. (don't mind - that will happen again and again...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Filter for the relevant lines: `... Get DeviceID^|find ":"') do ...` to get rid of empty entries and `echo %_DRIVE.LETTERS.USED:~0,-3%` to delete the last space/semicolon/space:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "skip=1 tokens=1,2 delims=: " %%a in ('WMIC LogicalDisk Where "DriveType='3'" Get DeviceID ^|find ":"') do (
   set "_DRIVE.LETTERS.USED=!_DRIVE.LETTERS.USED!%%a:\ ; "
)
echo %_DRIVE.LETTERS.USED:~0,3%
```

Answer (score 3):

The empty line is in fact an artefact (an orphaned carriage-return character) that appears when using `for /F` to convert the Unicode output of `wmic` to ASCII/ANSI text. To get rid of such things just wrap around another `for /F` loop<sup>*</sup>:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "skip=1" %%I in ('wmic LogicalDisk where "DriveType=3" get DeviceID') do (
    for /F %%J in ("%%I") do (
        set "_DRIVE.LETTERS.USED=!_DRIVE.LETTERS.USED!%%J\ ; "
    )
)
endlocal & echo %_DRIVE.LETTERS.USED%
```

I also removed the options `tokens` (default: `1`) and `delims` (default: <kbd>SPACE</kbd>, <kbd>TAB</kbd>) since they are not really needed here any more (splitting off the colon and then re-appending it in the loop body makes no sense).

---

A more general solution, which even works when there are <kbd>SPACEs</kbd> within the values, is to use the `/VALUE` option of `wmic`, because then the returned values are no longer padded with trailing <kbd>SPACEs</kbd>, which is the case without `/VALUE`. To split off the preceding value name in the changed output (like `DeviceID=C:`), set the appropriate `tokens` and `delims` options of the inner `for /F` loop:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('wmic LogicalDisk where "DriveType=3" get DeviceID /VALUE') do (
    for /F "tokens=1* delims==" %%J in ("%%I") do (
        set "_DRIVE.LETTERS.USED=!_DRIVE.LETTERS.USED!%%K\ ; "
    )
)
endlocal & echo %_DRIVE.LETTERS.USED%
```

This would remove any leading equal-to signs from the values, but this is not going to happen with the values at hand anyway, and this should generally happen extremely rarely.

---

<sub>*)  This two-loop method is credited to user [dbenham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1012053/dbenham) ‐ see his answer to [Why is the FOR /f loop in this batch script evaluating a blank line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14658784) as well as this external article [WMIC and FOR /F : A fix for the trailing <CR> problem](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4266).</sub>

Comment: Just noting: `"splitting off the colon and then re-appending it in the loop body makes no sense"` -  That's true only with this nested `for` approach. With a simple `for`, not removing the colon results in that ugly remaining `CR`.

Comment: @Stephan, in this particular case I think the (also default) _space_ delimiter would do the trick anyway since the original code returned `C:` + _space_s + _<CR>_`, so the _<CR>_ would disappear anyway...